# Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 - no aab

Tags: android, android-studio

after updating Android Studio to the latest version I can't create aab file.

That is, it is not present with me:
"Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps in Google Play App Signing".

[Screen found on the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYmu7.png)

[My Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLbqC.png)

but in the latest version of Android Studio there is no option to check "Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps in Google Play App Signing.

Comment: Seems like this option was removed, even if the documentation still includes it: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: So it has to be done through the terminal?
flutter build appbundle

Only that Google Play does not accept the aab file made by the terminal.
An error appears:
The uploaded APK file or Android application package was signed in debug mode. You need to sign it in final mode